# form validation error in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I've been following this tutorial by Envato on Tutplus: https://tutsplus.com/course/build-a-cms-in-codeigniter/. I'm at the part at which I want to validate login form. My problem is I can't use my form validation rule in login system. My code is given below:

**user_m.php**

```
<?php 
  class User_M extends MY_Model {

public $rules = array(  // I can't use this rules in my controller
   'email' => array(  // for email 
    'field' => 'email',
    'label' => 'Email',
    'rule'  => 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean'
    ),
    'password' => array(  // for password
    'field' => 'password',
    'label' => 'Password',
    'rule'  => 'trim|required'
     )
);

}
```

**user.php**

```
 <?php 

class User extends Admin_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function login()
{   
   // Set form
   $rules = $this->user_m->rules; // get the value from user_m model and it works well
       // this is not works. this is my problem
   $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);  

       // if we use this comment code then it works
   //$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'rim|required|valid_email|xss_clean'); 
   // $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

   // Process form
   if ( $this->form_validation->run() == TRUE )  { // show the error msg if form problem occurs 
       // We can login and redirect

    }

}
```

Comment: Its pretty simple -- You are defining the rules in your model - but then you are trying to call it from the controller. Also i did that tutorial and for a while i was calling my models "something_m" and thinking it was so cool. in fact i wrote a post  - and in writing it i figured out that actually its a terrible naming pattern. so my suggestion is name models specifically and controllers generally without any decoration.

Comment: suggest to just put all the form validation in the model, and then call it like: if ( $this->user_m->validateUserForm() == False ){ // show the form again } else { // go to another method and make the magic happen }

Answer (score 0):

You may try this (set the rules in your controller before you call `form_validation->run()` function)

```
public function login()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email',  'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password',  'trim|required');
    if ( $this->form_validation->run() )  {
        // validation passed
    }
    else {
        // validation failed
    }
}
```

Comment: you might notice this code works well, I just can not figure out what's wrong in my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You make sure that you have write **form_error('email');** and **form_error('password');** below email and password text boxes.
    Please call login view if validation error occurs.

```
public function login()
{
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email',  'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password',  'trim|required');
   if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
           **$this->load->view('login view path');**
        }else{write other code of redirect or any.....} 
}
```